# Node-red running on DietPi show gpio nodes as not available

Tags: raspberry-pi, node-red, gpio

So this, running the latest DietPi (DietPi_RPi-ARMv6-Bullseye) on Raspberry Pi zero W and using [node-red-node-pi-gpio](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-pi-gpio) to talk to hardware.

However after deployment I see this:

[image]

RPi.GPIO python library is installed, I also installed WiringPi which show everything in order.

**Not sure what's happening.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: What if anything is in the Node-RED logs?